# explicit loading of jaxws

Tags: jax-ws

Hi 
I want to load/use jaxws 2.2. But as java by default provides 2.1, i am not able to load it. I have tried it with "endorsed" dir and it is working fine.

Is there any way to do the same from my java code?

Regards

Dipankaj

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible to load from inside java as JVM while loading it has to use these new jar's placed under endorsed directory of jre.

One easy way is to write ant script to copy the jar's to java endorsed directory before starting.